# How to update value to firebase database with Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, http, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to make an upvote function. I have some posts stored in database with Firebase. I would like to let people upvote (or downvote) for a post.

Here is in my ctrl :

```
upvote(advice) {
    advice.votes = advice.votes + 1;
    return this.httpService.updateData(advice)
    .subscribe((res:Response) => {
        console.log('in subscribe', res);
    });
}
```

And in my service :

```
updateData (data:any): Observable<any> {

    let datas = JSON.stringify(data);
    const headers = { 'Authorization': 'secret' };

    return this.http.put(this.url + 'data.json', datas, headers)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log('finally');
        })
}
```

When I check the response in subscribe method inside the controller, I can see the updated value, but my database is now destroyed.

Before :

[image: Screenshot before the bug]

After :

[image]

As you can see, there no more real object after, it replaces everything. 
I think I have to change the url or check the post id, but I don't see how to do. 
I didn't find anything in the firebase documentation.. So if someone has an idea..

EDIT AFTER @Luke answer

I updated my code like this :

In my ctrl :

```
upvote(advice) {
    advice.votes = advice.votes + 1;
    return this.httpService.updateData(advice)
    .subscribe((res:Response) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res;
    })
}
```

And in the service :

```
getId() {
    this.db.list('data').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
        return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() }));
    }).subscribe(items => {
        return items.map(item => item.key);
    });
}

updateData (data:any): Observable<any> {

    let updateUrl = this.url + '-p1FFxUqY6u1_AZ3ER4eVUt';

    let datas = JSON.stringify(data);
    const headers = { 'Authorization': 'secret' };

    return this.http.put(updateUrl + 'data.json', datas, headers)
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log(e);
        })
        .finally(() => {
            console.log('finally');
        })
}
```

I can see the vote counter update in the logs and on the front, but not in the database. When I refresh the page the vote come back to 0. 
I think I just forgot something..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a new item to a location, you should use `POST` instead of `PUT`:

```
this.http.post(this.url + 'data.json', datas, headers)...
```

If you want to update an existing item by only providing partial data , you should use `PATCH` instead of `PUT`. If your HTTP client doesn't support sending `PATCH`, you can use a `GET` and specify `PATCH` in the `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header.

For full details on all of these, read the [Firebase documentation in saving data using the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data).

Comment: It's not for adding an item, it's for updating the vote's number of an item.

Comment: In that case your want to use `PATCH`, which (as [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data) says) is for "Update some of the keys for a defined path without replacing all of the data".

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I could not work on this this last days. thanks for your answer, I saw this documentation but I would like to find an example with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To update your data, you need to know the key of that particular item to put in your url; for example: your-firebase-url/.../L3-bvgdsggdgde. Something like this

```
updateData (data:any): Observable<any> {

        updateUrl = this.url + 'L3-bvgdsggdgde';

        let datas = JSON.stringify(data);
        const headers = { 'Authorization': 'secret' };

        return this.http.put(updateUrl + 'data.json', datas, headers)
            .catch((e) => {
                console.log(e);
            })
            .finally(() => {
                console.log('finally');
            })
    }
```

So, how to take the key from Firebase and reuse it? following this [Firebase doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md) when you get data from Firebase

```
constructor(afDb: AngularFireDatabase) {
  afDb.list('items').snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(action => ({ key: action.key, ...action.payload.val() }));
  }).subscribe(items => {
    return items.map(item => item.key);
  });
}
```

Your object will have a key property, reuse it in your upvote/update method.
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and sorry for the delay. I edited my question with your recommendation, but I don't succeed to store the updated value in db.